# showlabels change of font size

Tags: equations, fontsize, showlabels

I am using `\usepackage[left]{showlabels}` to print labels for my equations.

For example, I have an equation as:

```
\begin{equation}
x = a + b
\label{eqn:a_b}
\end{equation}
```

The label is printed as:

[image]

Sometimes the label names are long so I wanted to change the font size, I did that using the following line:

```
\renewcommand{\showlabelfont}{\tiny}
```

However, the underscore "_" in my label name gets replaced after I change the fontsize.

[image]

There is no more "_" in the printed label. What is going on?

Comment: Show a complete example. That makes it more easier to test your issue.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left]{showlabels}
\renewcommand{\showlabelfont}{\tiny} %COMMENT AND UNCOMMENT 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x = a + b
\label{eqn:a_b}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default definition uses the typewriter font which with OT1 is slightly differently encoded as the roman font. Either add \ttfamily, or load T1-encoding (recommended anyway) or both.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[left]{showlabels} 
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\showlabelfont}{\ttfamily\tiny} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{equation} x = a + b \label{eqn:a_b} \end{equation} 
\end{document}
```